# Gnome-disk-utility make my partition gone, how to restore it?

Tags: linux, partitioning, ntfs, arch-linux, gparted

My 12 y/o Acer v5-431 notebook have two Linux, Mint Xfce and a new installed Arch Linux last week, today i booted into my Arch and was trying to access my Linux Mint Home partition but i didnt see it on file manager so i open a terminal and mount it manually and it worked but how to make it mount automatically each time i booted into Arch?

I google it and found the solution using gnome-disk-utility, install the gnome disk and open it i selected my Linux Mint home partition then click on additional partition option and choose edit mount option, i disabled the user session defaults, choose the mount point of the Linux Mint home partition and press ok, i reboot my Arch Linux and it worked successfully.

Now is where i got the problem, this time i want to make my 360gb ntfs partition mounted automatically each boot using the same method before, i rebooted my Arch and then baaamp, the booting taking longer than usuall. When i logged into my desktop and mount the ntfs partition manually using terminal it says special device does not exist,
I use fdisk -l and see my ntfs(dev/sda8) partition was there:

```
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Ignoring extra data in partition table 8.
Ignoring extra data in partition table 8.
Ignoring extra data in partition table 8.
Disk /dev/sda: 465,78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: ST500LT012-9WS14
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9eca72f8

Device     Boot      Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048   50505727  50503680  24,1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2         50505728   58505215   7999488   3,8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3         58507262  976767039 918259778 437,9G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5         58507264  163842047 105334784  50,2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6        163844096  164376575    532480   260M 83 Linux
/dev/sda7        164378624  204800063  40421440  19,3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda8       2024287494 3004010606 979723113 467,2G 6c unknown

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 8 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

I open Gparted and it says "Can't have overlapping partitions." How can i restore my ntfs partition and its data?

Comment: Fastest and most effective way is to restore the last disk image. Certainly, before making changes to disk, you made an image!

Comment: @DrMoishePippik unfortunately i didn't create the disk image of my ntfs partition before

Comment: Solved i just have to delete and recreate the partition using fdisk.